# Android app fails to load deleted questions even if I have the rep to view them

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, android-app

Trying to view a deleted question in Android app fails, the app shows "Loading the question failed", and doesn't say why.

Comment: It doesn't appear the case but the answer to this question is the same.